# Select column names whose entries are not null

Tags: mysql, database-design, select, null

I would like to have a list of those columns of a table that have at least one not-`NULL` data entries in them.

In other words, I would like to get the column names for which the following returns at least one entry:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = "table_name"
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL
)
```

But this also returns the column names where all the entries are `NULL`.

So how do I get only those columns with non-`NULL` entries?

Comment: Sorry about my earlier answer, I tried to do it too quickly (which is why I deleted). Hopefully I can get some time today to answer you. If someone else doesn't beat me first :)

Comment: @DTest I would be very grateful if you figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's pick a sample table on my machine:

```
mysql> show create table weisci_jaws_staging2.users\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: users
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `passwd` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '2',
  `recovery_key` varchar(48) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `theme` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `editor` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `createtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `change_passwd` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `never_expire` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `bad_passwd_count` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `last_access` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_username_idx` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=160 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select count(1) from weisci_jaws_staging2.users;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|      117 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

With this table, here are two questions:

- Which columns are nullable ?
- Which columns are not nullable ?

This query will find out for you:

```
select is_nullable,GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) column_list
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'weisci_jaws_staging2'
and   table_name = 'users'
group by is_nullable;
```

Check out the result of that query for the table:

```
mysql> select is_nullable,GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) column_list
    -> from information_schema.columns
    -> where table_schema = 'weisci_jaws_staging2'
    -> and   table_name = 'users'
    -> group by is_nullable;
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| is_nullable | column_list                                                                                                                        |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NO          | id,never_expire,change_passwd,enabled,username,passwd                                                                              |
| YES         | recovery_key,last_access,bad_passwd_count,updatetime,createtime,last_login,editor,user_type,language,timezone,url,email,name,theme |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

OK, we have two lists. What do we learn from this?

- If you get two lists, no need to inspect the actual table because the table has non-NULL columns by definition.
- If you get one list, then

  - If you get only is_nullable='NO', no need to inspect the actual table because the table has non-NULL columns by definition.
  - If you get only is_nullable='YES', the actual table would be a little brittle. There would be no PRIMARY KEY, *you poor, tormented soul* !!! NOW, you have to resort to reading every row from the actual table.

If you are looking for just the non-null columns, then this would be your desired query:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) nonnull_columns
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'weisci_jaws_staging2'
and   table_name = 'users'
and   is_nullable = 'NO';
```

Here is the output of this query:

```
mysql> select GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) nonnull_columns
    -> from information_schema.columns
    -> where table_schema = 'weisci_jaws_staging2'
    -> and   table_name = 'users'
    -> and   is_nullable = 'NO';
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| nonnull_columns                                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| id,username,passwd,change_passwd,never_expire,enabled |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Removing the GROUP_CONCAT, you get this:

```
mysql> select column_name nonnull_column
    -> from information_schema.columns
    -> where table_schema = 'weisci_jaws_staging2'
    -> and   table_name = 'users'
    -> and   is_nullable = 'NO';
+----------------+
| nonnull_column |
+----------------+
| id             |
| username       |
| passwd         |
| change_passwd  |
| never_expire   |
| enabled        |
+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

**NOTE** : Please notice that I do not need to read the actual table's data content. That's far more efficient than reading the entire table.

## UPDATE 2012-11-15 13:40 EDT

The code from @sensware's answer gives `NULL` columns. The original question asked for `non-NULL` columns. I augmented the code to test just my table:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; -- to overcome default 1KB limitation
SELECT CONCAT(
         'SELECT * FROM ('
       ,  GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
              'SELECT ', QUOTE(TABLE_NAME), ' AS `table`,'
            , 'IF('
            ,   'COUNT(`', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'), '`),'
            ,   'NULL,'
            ,    QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME)
            , ') AS `column` '
            , 'FROM `',
            REPLACE(TABLE_SCHEMA, '`', '``'), '`.`',
            REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '`', '``'), '`'
            )
            SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
         )
       , ') t WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL'
       )
INTO   @sql
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'weisci_jaws_staging2'
AND    TABLE_NAME = 'users';
SELECT @sql\G
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is the output:

```
mysql> SET group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; -- to overcome default 1KB limitation
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT(
    ->          'SELECT * FROM ('
    ->        ,  GROUP_CONCAT(
    ->             CONCAT(
    ->               'SELECT ', QUOTE(TABLE_NAME), ' AS `table`,'
    ->             , 'IF('
    ->             ,   'COUNT(`', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'), '`),'
    ->             ,   'NULL,'
    ->             ,    QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME)
    ->             , ') AS `column` '
    ->             , 'FROM `',
    ->             REPLACE(TABLE_SCHEMA, '`', '``'), '`.`',
    ->             REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '`', '``'), '`'
    ->             )
    ->             SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
    ->          )
    ->        , ') t WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL'
    ->        )
    -> INTO   @sql
    -> FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    -> WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'weisci_jaws_staging2'
    -> AND    TABLE_NAME = 'users';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT @sql\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@sql: SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`id`),NULL,'id') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`username`),NULL,'username') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`passwd`),NULL,'passwd') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`user_type`),NULL,'user_type') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`recovery_key`),NULL,'recovery_key') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`name`),NULL,'name') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`email`),NULL,'email') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`url`),NULL,'url') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`timezone`),NULL,'timezone') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`language`),NULL,'language') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`theme`),NULL,'theme') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`editor`),NULL,'editor') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`last_login`),NULL,'last_login') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`createtime`),NULL,'createtime') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`updatetime`),NULL,'updatetime') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`change_passwd`),NULL,'change_passwd') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`never_expire`),NULL,'never_expire') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`bad_passwd_count`),NULL,'bad_passwd_count') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`last_access`),NULL,'last_access') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`enabled`),NULL,'enabled') AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users`) t WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
+-------+--------+
| table | column |
+-------+--------+
| users | theme  |
+-------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

This give NULL columns. The original question asked for non-NULL columns. I'll change the code to generated non-NULL. I'll do that by flipping the order of the `IF..COUNT`:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; -- to overcome default 1KB limitation
SELECT CONCAT(
         'SELECT * FROM ('
       ,  GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
              'SELECT ', QUOTE(TABLE_NAME), ' AS `table`,'
            , 'IF('
            ,   'COUNT(`', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'), '`),'
            ,    QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME)
            ,   ',NULL'
            , ') AS `column` '
            , 'FROM `',
            REPLACE(TABLE_SCHEMA, '`', '``'), '`.`',
            REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '`', '``'), '`'
            )
            SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
         )
       , ') t WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL'
       )
INTO   @sql
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'weisci_jaws_staging2'
AND    TABLE_NAME = 'users';
SELECT @sql\G
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Let's run it now...

```
mysql> SET group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; -- to overcome default 1KB limitation
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT(
    ->          'SELECT * FROM ('
    ->        ,  GROUP_CONCAT(
    ->             CONCAT(
    ->               'SELECT ', QUOTE(TABLE_NAME), ' AS `table`,'
    ->             , 'IF('
    ->             ,   'COUNT(`', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'), '`),'
    ->             ,    QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME)
    ->             ,   ',NULL'
    ->             , ') AS `column` '
    ->             , 'FROM `',
    ->             REPLACE(TABLE_SCHEMA, '`', '``'), '`.`',
    ->             REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '`', '``'), '`'
    ->             )
    ->             SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
    ->          )
    ->        , ') t WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL'
    ->        )
    -> INTO   @sql
    -> FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    -> WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'weisci_jaws_staging2'
    -> AND    TABLE_NAME = 'users';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT @sql\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@sql: SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`id`),'id',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`username`),'username',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`passwd`),'passwd',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`user_type`),'user_type',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`recovery_key`),'recovery_key',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`name`),'name',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`email`),'email',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`url`),'url',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`timezone`),'timezone',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`language`),'language',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`theme`),'theme',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`editor`),'editor',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`last_login`),'last_login',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`createtime`),'createtime',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`updatetime`),'updatetime',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`change_passwd`),'change_passwd',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`never_expire`),'never_expire',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`bad_passwd_count`),'bad_passwd_count',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`last_access`),'last_access',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users` UNION ALL SELECT 'users' AS `table`,IF(COUNT(`enabled`),'enabled',NULL) AS `column` FROM `weisci_jaws_staging2`.`users`) t WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
+-------+------------------+
| table | column           |
+-------+------------------+
| users | id               |
| users | username         |
| users | passwd           |
| users | user_type        |
| users | recovery_key     |
| users | name             |
| users | email            |
| users | url              |
| users | timezone         |
| users | language         |
| users | editor           |
| users | last_login       |
| users | createtime       |
| users | updatetime       |
| users | change_passwd    |
| users | never_expire     |
| users | bad_passwd_count |
| users | last_access      |
| users | enabled          |
+-------+------------------+
19 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK it works now. There is a problem still present. The query requires reading the entire table. My test table only has 117 rows and 20 columns. ***What about bigger tables with millions of rows or dozens of columns***? I am not going to speculate because I know that the code would be orders of magnitude worse.

That's why I recommend my answer

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) nonnull_columns
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'weisci_jaws_staging2'
and   table_name = 'users'
and   is_nullable = 'NO';
```

or

```
select column_name nonnull_column
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'weisci_jaws_staging2'
and   table_name = 'users'
and   is_nullable = 'NO';
```

because the actual data content does not have to be inspected.

The augmented code I made should only be used on a table where all column allow `NULL` values, which is extremely rare.

Answer (score 3):

I think this was answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091272/find-all-those-columns-which-have-only-null-values-in-a-mysql-table

Code was copied below:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; -- to overcome default 1KB limitation

SELECT CONCAT(
         'SELECT * FROM ('
       ,  GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
              'SELECT ', QUOTE(TABLE_NAME), ' AS `table`,'
            , 'IF('
            ,   'COUNT(`', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'), '`),'
            ,   'NULL,'
            ,    QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME)
            , ') AS `column` '
            , 'FROM `', REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, '`', '``'), '`'
            )
            SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
         )
       , ') t WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL'
       )
INTO   @sql
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```