# A function to check if a column allows NULL

Tags: mysql, null, functions, update

Is there a way to write an insert/update query that checks if a column allows `NULLs`: If it does set the column to `NULL`, and `''` (empty string) otherwise?

I would be something like:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET field = IF(A_FUNCTION_TO_CHECK_IF_ALLOWS_NULL(), NULL, '');
```

Comment: Would this work for you? `UPDATE mytable SET field = ''; UPDATE mytable SET field = NULL;` (the 2nd statement will not succeed if the column has `NOT NULL` attribute.

Comment: @ypercube I'm trying to avoid errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html

In the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table there is a IS_NULLABLE column.

You could turn it into a function, I imagine, but I would probably put this logic in an outer part.

Comment: That should do it. In fact, I wrote up how to collect all null and non-null column names for a given table using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28745/877. Your direct answer gets +1 !!!

Comment: What do you mean by "outer part" ? The program that is connecting to MySQL?

Comment: @Wolf480pl in whatever generates the SQL statement.  Typically your schema is not changing that frequently.  I was thinking you would have to be generating this code.  Because putting it in manually is no more efficient than just matching the code to the schema in the first place.

Comment: So basically a clientside schema cache?

Comment: @Wolf480pl I guess so.  Certainly you don't need to be inquiring about the schema in every call.

Answer (score 4):

[Cade's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29620/97765) is correct, but the information directly from the link:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'mytable'
```